# images as buttons in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, button

I want to use a common link in every page of my wordpress site.
I want it to show as a button or image or infographic and when one clicks on it it opens a new page in a new window.
I want an image to be used as button and i would apply it on every page of the website.

But HOW ??
 How to use a clickable image as a button in wordpress ??

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your question that you do not search for code , but more like an advice on how to do so using the normal wordpress UI ..

If that is the case , All you have to do is specify the LINK for the image in the media upload dialog when you insert the image ..

That being said, I believe that what you want to do , again , if I understood right, is a misuse of the wordpress as a system. Wordpress is not , and should not IMHO , be used like an old fashioned HTML page where everything is made manually ..

And again, it is also possible that I understood you wrong . if so, please elaborate a bit ..

Comment: Thanks..anyways but didn't understand wat u wrote...!! I just want to make a info-graphic/image to attract viewers for some of my program and use it on every page of my website to drag them to a form wen they click on it... plugins for short-codes or button/link generations, doesn't seem to look that effective.. Yes, I usually make changes to the main theme code as per my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a way to make images link to other pages, make sure to wrap your  tags with the corresponding  tags. To open a link in a new window, use target="_blank" inside your anchor tag.

I agree with Obmerk Kronen on not using Wordpress as any other HTML editor. Edit your template (with a Child Theme if needed) instead of hard coding things into a new page or post.

Comment: Thanks... I tried using many plugins for a good looking button and tried placing images on them but...nothing worked...!! I ,ll try again with wat u said...

Comment: Can you provide me with a link? I might be able to help better that way.